# Fetch drupal themes from a directory

Tags: drupal, themes

I have a requirement of fetch drupal themes stored in sites/all/themes folder. I want to show thier image if exist and all there information.. PLease tell me a way I can do it. All I just want to know is there any function exist in drupal which fetch theme from a directory or any function relavent to it. If not then from where should I get started.. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Faizan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [list_themes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/list_themes/6) function, together with [drupal_get_path('theme', $theme_name)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/6)

the screenshot image is called screenshot.jpg i think